# What pattern/solution should i use to avoid `instanceof` in this case?

Tags: java, oop, instanceof

What pattern/solution should I use to avoid `instanceof` in this case? I have googled a bit and found  that visitor pattern is the way to go but I don't think that applies in this case. also other solutions like adding isTestable() method to phrase in kind of hacker solution and I am seeking a standard way to go.

```
    public class PhraseOwner(){
    List<Phrase> phrases;    
        public void switchTestMode(){
          for(Phrase phrase : phrases){
            if(phrase instanceof Testable())
              (Testable)phrase.switchTestMode();
             }

           }
     }

     public interface Phrase{
        //STUFF
     }

     public interface Testable{
        public void switchTestMode();
     }
```

I have two types of classes , those who have implemented just `Phrase` interface and those who have implemented both `Phrase` and `Testable` interfaces.

```
public class A implements Phrase,Testable{
  public void switchTestMode(){
    //stuff
  }
}

public class B implements Phrase{
    //stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: Are all `Phrase` also `Testable`? If yes, `Phrase` could extends `Testable`.

Comment: Why not have a `List<Phrase>` and a `List<Testable>`? How to you add to the list?

Comment: @LaurentG no not all the phrases are testable

Comment: @fge i am trying to use polymorphism as much as i can

Comment: Simply don't avoid the instanceof!

Comment: But what is the point to iterate over Phrase and invoke method from Testable interface? Maybe you can avoid it.

Comment: @ArneBurmeister i have learned that there are two kind of programmers which hate instance of and which don't and i am non :D some compare instance of with go-to

Comment: Exactly how do phrases get added?

Comment: @bohemian public void addPhrase(Phrase phrase){phrases.add(phrase)} i didnt write it because i thought it was not relevent to main question

Comment: I think you should not mix different types of objects in a list. However, you could of course force another interface upon both of the classes. ITestExists or something that you ask if it has test methods or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visitor gathers a same kind of operation for different or same hierarchies of objects.
**In your case, it's not**, since one of the object missed the concept of testing.

As `Phrase` is not `Testable` (or the reverse), I wouldn't make a `List<Phrase>` type.
**Don't mix apples with oranges.** Generics for collections were primary invented to avoid this case.

You have to reconsider your code design by discerning `List<Phrase>` from `List<Testable>`, or improving the polymorphism by building a hierarchical link, if a link does exist.

Comment: what you mean by 'You have to reconsider your code design by discerning List<Phrase> from List<Testable>, or improving the polymorphism by building a hierarchical link' you mean make testable also implement phrase ?

Comment: @dave If you think that all `Phrase` ARE `Testable` or the reverse, make one extends the other, both implementing the concerned method. Otherwise, avoid mixing them in one common container.

Comment: if testable extends phrase then methods in testable wont be necessarily present in phrase. so i should add testable methods to phrase too so what will be the point of testable interface at first place?

Comment: @dave So if you end up with a "non-sense" to link them, just rework the code in order to target your `Testable` specific code to `Testable` objects only. Unfortunately, we haven't the context in your OP to rethink the logic. Your current code is like mixing `Integer` with `String`, and checking for `substring` implementation method... Fortunately, there is ALWAYS a solution to avoid those cases :), otherwise programs would really be ugly. Design patterns are never a solution for a lack of "good-sense".

Comment: i guess i can make Testable to extend Phrase then i will have oranges and other kind of oranges in my basket. but still i cant see a way to avoid instance of

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't avoid `instanceof` if polymorphism does not exist in the hierarchy. IMO, let `Testable` distinct from `Phrase` and be sure to only deal with `Testable`s objects when you call for `Testable` behavior (without need of `instanceof` of course, that is not very OOP oriented). I'm really sure it's possible if you rethink your whole concerned design.

Comment: thank you i will try and try until death part me apart from programming ;)

Comment: That's why software programming is often compared to "Art" ;) and makes the beauty of the job :)

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to create an abstract class for phrases which are not testable, and just make `.switchTestMode()` do nothing:

```
public abstract class NonTestablePhrase
    implements Phrase, Testable
{
    @Override
    public final void switchTestMode()
    {
    }
}
```

Then you could declare `public class B extends NonTestablePhrase`.

Comment: Would technically work but what about a future potential dozen of possible cases: NonTestable, NonPrintable, NonWritable etc... would be a mess and huge amount of "do nothing" methods.

Comment: @Mik378 yes, but then the OP doesn't share much of her goals here... Limited scope, limited answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is to add a Boolean value to both classes that denotes whether or not a Phrase is testable.  If it is testable, it should also implement the Testable interface.  Then, you could check that Boolean value on any phrase, without knowing a priori whether or not it was a testable class.  I would, however, in the initializer, use instanceof() to set that Boolean!  I would also overload the initializer so that normally the Boolean is set to False unless specifically instantiated to True.

Comment: Not an OOP solution ... Field designing type is not a useful replacement for polymorphism at all. Similar to the `instanceof` "issue" since MANUAL decision has to be taken into account.

Comment: Wrong and wrong.  Question asked to avoid using instance of on that  specific case, it never stated "give me a non OOP solution for a problem which only makes sense in an OOP paradigm." Furthermore, an initializer set variable is only manual at the point of coding the initializer for any class that may be used but may or may not be testable.  Again, this question is so beyond what anyone should do with Java so as to be unanswerable.  My answer, though you judge it to be non-useful, is still an answer that differs from yours and may suit the asker enough to get a vote!  You had your chance :P

Comment: When someone asks how to cross the crosswalk, I would not advise him to take an underground ;). My answer would not be based on the result: he MUST be on the other side of the road, but rather on the explanation of the most helpful and efficient way to go, regarding the common way. Your answer is still an answer yes, by the way, that's why I didn't downvote ;) I interpret the question as being: "how should I avoid to check for `Testable`" rather than just the specific technical aspect `instanceof`. In this case, a `Boolean` is uglier than an `instanceof`, since being internal and so redundant.

Comment: > Why get wrapped around the axle over it?  There are just too many people coding in Java procedurally; root cause being that it simply ignores the essence of OOP => sending messages, not requesting for data as C language and others do. I see stackoverflow as being a hall of great programming lessons, not a hall of "screwdrivers" to make things work.

Comment: To deny someone the ability to solve a problem procedurally is ludicrous.  OOP is just a paradigm.  You can facilitate it as much as you want, but at the end of the day, declarative statements are always needed.  On top of that, objects themselves don't solve problems.  Forcing OOP onto someone won't make their algorithm function any better.   I also disagree that it's a bad thing to address only the issue at hand.  Even though this problem was narrow in scope, it did not prevent us from having a discussion with great breadth.  Narrow focus forces concise answers, which gives SO it's value.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could have testable and non testable classes implement either the testable or non testable interface respectively, while depending on polymorphism to allow you to call the method 'switchtestmode' on either interface!  You wouldn't have to test the instance, but you'd have to implement the non testable interface for all non testable classes ( Something which may or may not be feasible for you)

Answer (score 0):

The use of `instanceof` may be avoided by using [`Class#isAssignableFrom()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) instead:

```
if (Testable.class.isAssignableFrom(phrase.getClass())) {
    ((Testable) phrase).switchTestMode();
}
```

Admittedly this may be considered "semantics", as while *technically* it achieves the goal, it more or less does the same thing.